# How to use Jquery to highlight svg map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, svg, jquery-svg

im having a problem highlighting states in map using jquery.i have implemented it using javascript. `
    
    
        SVG Illustrator Test

```
    <object data="map_with_hover.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="alphasvg" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
<script>
    var a = document.getElementById("alphasvg");

    //it's important to add an load event listener to the object, as it will load the svg doc asynchronously
    a.addEventListener("load",function(){
        var svgDoc = a.contentDocument; //get the inner DOM of alpha.svg
        var delta = svgDoc.getElementById("states"); //get the inner element by id
        delta.addEventListener("mouseover",function(evt){ evt.target.setAttributeNS(null,"opacity","0.5");},false);    //add behaviour
        delta.addEventListener("mouseout",function(evt){ evt.target.setAttributeNS(null,"opacity","1");},false);    //add behaviour
    },false);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

`

by this code states get highlighted easily but i want to do it in jquery as i also wanna add tooltip,so that on mouseover state name will also be displayed.
so basically i wanna know how to use SVG's id or class or tags to perfrom different action by using jquery.

Comment: @Phrogz That's not true, one can select SVG elements much the same as HTML via jQuery, (using id's works great for me). The one difference is that the SVG file must be embedded directly into the DOM. In this case you are correct, as he is using an object tag.

Comment: @Jlange I stand embarrassed and corrected, and have now deleted my misinformation. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Krunal Shah Did my solution below help you at all?

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called [jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) this might help you.

Comment: nope not getting it... it'll be better if i get to know how to use jquery within svg file or this html..so that i can directly use svg elements in my jquery selector.

Answer (score 0):

You should embed the file directly into your HTML, (using SVG tags). This will allow you to select the different SVG elements using plain jQuery. See [here](http://www.restingrobot.com/testing/MapDemo.html)

Feel free to use this code as it is very basic, and I pulled the map from Wikipedia.